# Delete a range of rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet which has alarmingly huge (>55MB) even though there are only 3 sheets each containing 55 rows and 10 columns. With sheet 3 having data links from sheet1. Though I noticed that all rows after the actual data (55 rows) have `0` and the same on sheet 3 where links exist have `#REF!`.

I am attaching the screenshots. Please have a look and suggest a solution.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: What do you have in column A and J and K did you copy paste a whole column or drag the formula down? you have to explain?

Comment: If you hit `Ctrl+End`, which cell is selected?

Comment: What ranges do you want to clear? `0` and `#REF` cells?

Comment: @yass I copy and pasted the links.

Comment: @BruceWayne 0 and #REF both. I want to keep first 51 rows only. why did I want to remove? Because I suspect the 0 and #REF are making the file huge.

Comment: @Werrf I am on Mac. I tried `Cmd + End` and `Ctrl+End` for both it was hoping cell in the next row.

Comment: To quickly remove all those zeros, click the `51` on the left, to select the entire row. Then press `CTRL+SHIFT+DOWN` and it should go to the end of the data/end of the worksheet. Then right click --> Delete or just click `DELETE` key.

Comment: Just curious about the root of the issue ..how'd you *get* that data there in the first place? Is it a macro? Copy/paste? Formula? Or was it just given to you that way to begin with?